# Two X11 on single adapter

Tags: linux, x11

I have a laptop and I would like to configure it in a way that two persons could work on it at the same time. What I made up is: One person uses embedded keyboard, screen and touch pad. The second one uses TV connected via HDMI and external keyboard and mouse.
So, the first question is: Is it feaseable at all? If so then where could I find any tutorial on how to do it?

I will appreciate if you tell me what makes my idea not possible to implement if the case it's not feaseable:)

Comment: Why not just buy another computer.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You just have to setup two Xserver (X11), one managing embedded devices, the other one managing external devices. We can't answer you here, but you will find how to do it searching on internet.

Comment: But I do not need two adapters, right? Bucause most of the time I can only see solutions related to two graphic cards...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with finding a proper solution was that I didn't ask a proper question to google:) **X11 multiseat** is what I was looking for. Example tutorials:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatOneCard
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg_multiseat